# Two separate bibliographies at the end of an article

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, article, multibib

I would like to write a review article that contains two list of references. One list would be the one from resulted review articles. The second one would be all other articles. I am using TeXworks.

I am trying to use `multibib`. I would like to end up with two reference lists, one after the other.

Reference list 1

Higgins 2009 
...

Reference list 2

Cox 1982 
...

My `.tex` code can be found here. I also have created two `.bib` files in the same folder *bibliography1* and *bibliography2*.

```
\documentclass{bmcart}


\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{pri}{Primary sources}
\newcites{sec}{Secondary sources}
\begin{document}
...
\cite{citationFromBibliography1}
\cite{citationFromBibliography2}
...
\begin{backmatter}
\bibliographystylepri{bmc-mathphys}
\bibliographypri{bibliography1}
\bibliographystylesec{bmc-mathphys}
\bibliographysec{bibliography2}

\end{backmatter}
\end{document}
```